Connect to Snowflake using Azure Data Factory
I am trying to move data from ADLS Gen2 into Snowflake using ADF.
The linked service connection is getting timed out with the below error-

I have entered the warehouse, database , username, password and account name but it does not work.
Using the same values, I am able to run the query in Snowflake warehouse.
Can anyone please advise?

Hi - I don’t think you’ve provided enough information for anyone to be able to help you. It could be a network issue: does your network permit this connection; does Snowflake have a network policy that would block this? If you include a role in the connection does that work? Can you update the question with the connection definition (obviously obfuscating your actual URL, username, password)

According to this, you will get The operation has timed out issue due to firewall blocking the network traffic while connecting to snowflake. You can check the firewall rules in the Snowflake account and the network where the ADF is running. Make sure your data factory network is allowing to access snowflake.
If your network is private, then set up a managed private endpoint from Azure Data Factory to Snowflake by following this document.
Create snowflake linked service with created managed Vnet IR as shown below:

It will test successfully without any error. For more information you can refer to MS Q&A question.
